# How to boost a post using facebook graph API?

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, guzzle

I have been working with Facebook Graph API and first tried to create an Ad with Graph API Explorer but its returning error as

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1487888,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Tracking Pixel Required",
    "error_user_msg": "A tracking pixel is required for ads in a campaign with conversions as its objective.",
    "fbtrace_id": "A99MpM3xULaMsmp_LcmRLXo"
  }
}
```

I tried with many other combinations and each time returns some error.

I read Facebook Developer Documentation,but it's not clear about Ad and other related APIs.

FYI,I am trying to implement this with Guzzle in Laravel.Before trying to boost a post i created a Campaign and then an Adset and used an existing Facebook Post to try in Graph API Explorer,but with every combination returns some error.

Is there any simple way to just boost a post with Facebook Graph API Explorer with least parameters without returning any errors.

Thanks.

Comment: can u show the request you are making?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your web-site's domain with Facebook.

- Go to `Events Manager` > `Aggregated Events`.
- There select your domain, and set `Event Priority`.
- Finally, you will need to wait 3 days, then you can use those Events in Ads.

Also, each time you edit said `Event Priority` you will need to wait for 3 days, in meantime, you're NOT able to use that Event or any event with lower priority.

If you change/remove priority of an Event that is being used, then all Ad-sets using that Event will stop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Are you certain this is the case?

Comment: @codewiz These where the steps last I tried, but if the process has changed, feel free to edit my answer.